# How to create subfolder on mailbox from command line

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

On a CentOS 7 machine running Postfix and Dovecot how could I create subfolder named 'Bulk' on a inbox trough command line?

I thought to use the `maildirmake` command but this returns "maildirmake command not found".

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A Maildir is simply a directory that has the `cur`, `tmp` and `new` subdirectories.

IMAP Folders are usually simply subdirectories inside the main Maildir whose names start with a period, and which in turn are themselves Maildirs. They must also contain a  zero-length file named maildirfolder. See http://www.courier-mta.org/maildir.html

That makes it trivial to create new folders with the `mkdir` command.

```
mkdir /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk
mkdir /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/new
mkdir /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/tmp
mkdir /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/cur
touch /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/maildirfolder
```

By making use of shell expansion you can  reduce that to a single mkdir command:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/{cur,tmp,new} 
touch /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk/maildirfolder
```

An IMAP subfolder  is not nested in the parents Maildir folder, but  represented as a directory on the some levels as the parent, with a name that starts with a leading dot `.` , the name of the parent folder, a second dot `.` and then the name of the sub folder, i.e. a subfolder "Serverfault" in you "Bulk" folder may look like:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk.Serverfault/{cur,tmp,new}
touch /path/to/Maildir/.Bulk.Serverfault/maildirfolder
```

Comment: Dovecot *can* be configured with this dot-notation for subfolders (and thus ensure some compatibility to certain other mail servers), but could just as well be configured to have each element of the path be a real filesystem folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using the `doveadm mailbox create`  command to create additional folders in mailboxes. It creates the necessary `cur`, `tmp` and `new` subdirectories.